# With Java 8 which version of sonar-ant-task need to be used?

Tags: ant, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I am using ant script for Sonar code scan .Currently with 'sonar-ant-task-2.2.jar' i am able to execute scan for Java 7.
With Java 8 which version of sonar-ant-task need to be used ?

Thanks & Regards

Ganesh Rao

Comment: Why not using [the latest v2.5](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Ant) altogether ?

Comment: Do you use SonarQube 5.6+?

Answer (score 2):

Read point #2 of Prerequisites at [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Ant). Use *At least the minimal version of Java supported by your SonarQube server is in use*.

See [this](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements), any JRE v8 will do.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Ant) of the latest scanner you will find this Prerequisites section:

- SonarQube is already installed
- At least the minimal version of Java supported by your SonarQube server is in use
- The language plugins for each of the languages you wish to analyze are installed
- You have read Analyzing Code Source.
- Ant 1.7.1 or higher

So using Java 8 is not a problem if you are using SonarQube 5.6+ and using the latest scanner will resolve some issues (see the [changelog](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/ANTTASK/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:changelog-panel)).